# i have edit text bottom of screen. but i want, it should go top of the screen when i start entering some value with keyboard

Tags: android

i have EditText bottom of screen. but i want, it should go top of the screen when i start entering some value with keyboard.

[image]

as per image, Email id,Password are bottom of the screen. I want it goes up as top of screen (it means that facebook login & google login will disappear) like second image.

[image]

I have used below code in this activity under manifest.xml

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
```

but unable to get desired screen as per second image Please suggest me what can i do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Add one more value to windowSoftInputMode like below,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Comment: No it is not working . I want bottom two "Email & password" top of the screen as per second image.

Comment: so, do you want two edittext at the top of screen and the social login button at the bottom of the screen ?

Comment: No when i click on the Email id layout starts from Email id should go top of the screen and if it will go up then google login and facebook login will disappear.

Comment: okay, then if you have'nt set inputType to both of the edittext then set firts and then try it out.

Comment: i have set for both

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done using these (android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan") flags.
Will suggest a work around to achieve the desired. 
First of all have upper layout (FB & Gmail login) in one single layout (Ex LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) so that you can show/hide this layout.

Now set focus change listener on Email ID and Password, and check if any of these gets the focus hide above layout (facebook & google login) and whenever both the edittext loses the focus show the layout again.

```
editTextEmail.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
     if(!hasFocus){
       //check if password has focus as we need to consider both the edittext. If both don't have the focus then show the FB & Gmail login.
     }
   }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your views inside `ScrollView` and when focus changed you can scroll it up and down

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (v.getId() == _passwordText.getId()) {
                    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
                                        }
                                    }
                    );
                } else {
                    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.getTop());
                                        }
                                    }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    };
```